# What is $\sqrt{(-1)^2}$

Tags: terminology, radicals

This question is primarily terminology based. In that $\sqrt{}$ denotes the principal square root. 
Here are two reasoning

1. $\sqrt{(-1)^2}=1$  since $\sqrt{(-1)^2}=\sqrt{1}$ which we know has a principal square root of $1$.
2. Or  $\sqrt{(-1)^2}=-1$ since $\sqrt{(e^{\pi i})^2}=\sqrt{e^{2\pi i}}=e^{\pi i}=-1$

Which reasoning is correct and why? Also if possible can you leave a source.

Comment: $\sqrt{a^2}=|a|$ in general, for $a$ a real number. Try to avoid using complex numbers with $\sqrt{z}$, unless you want to abandon a lot of the usual features of $\sqrt{z}$, or you want to use a multi-valued function.

Comment: The issue with the second derivation is that it is not generally true that $\sqrt{e^x}=e^{x/2}$; this holds for real $x$ but for complex $x$ it can fail if you interpret $\sqrt{}$ as the principal square root.

Answer (score 3):

The first one is correct.

In the second one, $\sqrt{e^{2\pi i}}=e^{\pi i}$ is wrong. Should be $\sqrt{e^{2\pi i}}=|e^{\pi i}|=1$  (This stands of course under that assumption of knowing $e^{\pi i}$ is real).

Answer (score 1):

$\sqrt{(-1)^2} = \sqrt{1} = 1$

Comment: The last equality is incorrect.

Comment: @guest: The OP gave a correct answer. A misguided editor added the $\pm$ in there.

Comment: @HarishChandraRajpoot. Why did you edit this and replaced a correct answer by an incorrect one?

Comment: Actually, there was no information about the question. It was simply $\sqrt{(-1)^2}=\sqrt{1}=?$ So. mathematically, I corrected it as $\pm 1$ but for this particular question, answer is absolutely $1$ as you gave. It isn't my fault but still I was misled by the statement only.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

$(e^{2\pi i})=(\cos(2\pi)+i\sin(2\pi))=1+0i=1$

$\sqrt{1}=1$

Answer (score 0):

according to the absolute definition
$$\sqrt{x^2}=|x|=|-1|=1$$